# How can I save just the last result of ping (using linux terminal)?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, ping, rtti

I have this bash command bellow (I think this is bash) but it's not overriding the last result. I've tried with only one ">" and ">|" as well, but no success.

My goal is to save only the last line on a .txt file (if possible just save the "time" parameter of ping) using linux terminal (I'm using Ubuntu 18.04).

```
while true; do (ping www.stackoverflow.com) >> rtt_test.txt; sleep 5; done
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect output to a file and stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/418896/608639), [Shell output redirection inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2952809/608639), etc. Also see Bash manual, [Chapter 20. I/O Redirection](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html), and pay attention to "truncate" versus "append".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make ping exit without having to hit cntrl+c, use either `-c <number of pings to send>` or `-w <number of seconds to run for>`. Then using a single `>` will replace the output file with the new results each time.

If you want just the time to send a single ping, you can use `ping -c 1 www.stackoverflow.com | head -2 | tail -1 | cut -d "=" -f 4 > myfile`.